# Add existing user to existing group apache ranger

Tags: rest, apache-ranger

im looking at `apache Ranger`  rest API to add an existing internal user/users to an existing internal group.

I have been looking at the docs and cant seem to find something useful,is there an API for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following api call:-

```
curl -ivk -u admin:admin -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":13,"createDate":"2020-12-23T07:55:04Z","updateDate":"2020-12-23T07:55:04Z","owner":"rangerusersync","updatedBy":"rangerusersync","name":"atlas","password":"*****","description":"atlas - add from Unix box","groupIdList":[6,59,4,131,133],"groupNameList":["atlas","hadoop","shadow"],"status":0,"isVisible":1,"userSource":1,"userRoleList":["ROLE_USER"],"otherAttributes":"{\"full_name\":\"atlas\",\"original_name\":\"atlas\"}"}'  -X PUT https://RANGER_HOST:6182/service/xusers/users
```

Its little bit big but if user is already added to ranger then run following api to get the id information for users:-

```
curl -ivk -u admin:admin -H "Accept : application/json" -X GET https://RANGER_HOST:6182/service/xusers/users
```

Once you have IDs for all users, you can run following curl api to get the json formatted data which you can use to modify and then use PUT method in first API I mentioned:-

```
curl -ivk -u admin:admin -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET https://RANGER_HOST:6182/service/xusers/users/13
```

Above Curl api should return something like following:-

```
{"id":13,"createDate":"2020-12-23T07:55:04Z","updateDate":"2020-12-23T16:45:14Z","owner":"rangerusersync","updatedBy":"admin","name":"atlas","password":"*****","description":"atlas - add from Unix box","groupIdList":[133,6],"groupNameList":["apitest","atlas","hadoop","shadow","ssb"],"status":0,"isVisible":1,"userSource":1,"userRoleList":["ROLE_USER"],"otherAttributes":"{\"full_name\":\"atlas\",\"original_name\":\"atlas\"}"}
```

you have to modify `"groupIdList":[133,6]` from the above output copy entire output and pass it with PUT method as shown in the first api call mentioned above.

Comment: looks good, il give it a try,
one question though, will there be issues if the groupIdList wont be exact to the groupNameList?

Comment: @coding_potato no need to worry about groupNameList, keep updating groupIdList

Comment: Thank you! Btw is there a way to select multiple users with the api, didnt doesnt seem i can like /xusers/users/username/{several comma separated usernames}

Comment: I don't think thee is a way, but you can try to run for loop in preferred language including shell

Comment: i wanted to reduce api calls, but a loop will do for now . thanks :)

Comment: Hi @rikamamanus I always got 405 Method Not Allowed when trying your method above. any clue what I miss? Thank you